# ¿Por que el formulario de mi proyecto no se envia al hacer click al boton de submit?

Tags: html

Por alguna extraña razon el formulario no se envia al hacer click al boton de submit. Es la primera vez que me pasa y no logro entonctrar la solucion.

Dejo el codigo del repositorio y subido a netlify para que puedan verlo en vivo y testearlo. Agradeceria muchisimo la ayuda.

https://github.com/Michelgimenez/Portafolio
https://practical-colden-8ee7f5.netlify.app/

Comment: El código mínimo para identificar el problema va en tu pregunta por favor, checa como hacer un [mcve] y [ask]

Comment: cambia el boton que tienes por un input de tipo submit: `<input type="submit"  class="contact__form-submit" value="Enviar mensaje">`

Comment: Aclara además en donde está dicho código, sino tendríamos que buscarlo persona por persona... y está en index.html - linea 301 hasta 350

Comment: Hola tecnobyte, cambie el button por un input y todo sigue igual... Esta es mi primer pregunta, disculpen los errores